# How to avoid rendering element as simple as possible

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a reactJS component that looks like this :

```
var LikeCon = React.createClass({
    render(){
        return this.renderLikeButton(this.props.like, this.props.likeCount)
    },
    renderLikeButton(like, likeCount){
        var content;
        var tmpLikeCount;

        if(likeCount < 1){
            tmpLikeCount = "";
        }
        else{
            tmpLikeCount = likeCount;
        }


        if(like == 1){
            content = <div className="likeButConAct"><div className="likeB">&nbsp;</div><div className="likeCount">{tmpLikeCount}</div></div>
        }
        else{
            content = <div className="likeButCon"><div className="likeB">&nbsp;</div><div className="likeCount">{tmpLikeCount}</div></div>
        }
        return content;
    }
});
```

Say that I want to hide the likeCount element if there is no likes. How do I do this as simple as possible? I don´t want another component to render this.

Comment: what's the difference between `likeButConAct` and `likeButCon`? why do you have `like` and `likeCount`? Are they both number?

Comment: likeButConAct is when the user have set it to liked(when like is true) and likeCount explains how many likes there is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your variable is null or undefined then React simply won't render it. That means your conditional code can be as simple as:

```
var tmpLikeCount;

if(likeCount >= 1){
    tmpLikeCount = likeCount;
}
```

But I think you can make your code even simpler using class sets:

http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/class-name-manipulation.html

```
var LikeCon = React.createClass({
    render(){
        var likeCountCmp;
        var classes = React.addons.classSet({
            likeButCon: true,
            active: this.props.like
        });

        if(this.props.likeCount > 0) {
            likeCountCmp = <div className="likeCount">{this.props.likeCount}</div>;
        }

        return (
            <div className={classes}>
                <div className="likeB">&nbsp;</div>
                {likeCountCmp}
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

A final variation that I think will work is to use an implicit function return:

```
var LikeCon = React.createClass({
    render(){
        var classes = React.addons.classSet({
            likeButCon: true,
            active: this.props.like
        });

        return (
            <div className={classes}>
                <div className="likeB">&nbsp;</div>
                {this.getLikeCountCmp()}
            </div>
        )
    },

    getLikeCountCmp: function() {
        if(this.props.likeCount > 0) {
            return <div className="likeCount">{this.props.likeCount}</div>;
        }
    }
});
```

if we don't specifically return anything from `getLikeCountCmp`, we end up with `undefined`, which React renders as nothing.

Note that I'm a bit confused with your `like == 1` comparison - should that be true/false rather than a number? I've assumed `this.props.like` will be true or false in my examples. That means it'd be called with:

```
<LikeCon like={true|false} likeCount={5} />
```

Comment: Your last example looks more complicated. I feel that react is making the markup rendering a bit of a pain. The logic are easy, the problem is how to get the proper markup to the page and with react/JSX it involves extra work to get this going. Just by looking at your last example of LikeCon Im not really sure what it will render, I really have to put my mind to know whats happening here. My example was aiming to be as simple end self explainable as possible. The best would be to pack the HTML in a string and then render it but this is not the ReactJS way. the like is 1/0 to save some space.

Comment: All I want is to easy and simple create the markup for tha page. It should be vary clear by just looking on the code what the page really will get. So far React have not shown my any easy way of doing this? I am used to the ASP.NET MVC where I type the logic in the HTML and this is MUCH more readable then jumping back and forth in the react with functions and what not. Is there really no simplier way to render the markup with react? Maybe switching to regular javascript is much better where I can buld html strings?

Comment: I don't see how it's complicated at all. If you return nothing, you render nothing. If you don't like the last example with the function, use the one before it with the likeCountCmp. All of this has very little to do with React and a lot to do with composing good JavaScript - the only react-specific stuff is the classSet.

Comment: also "the like is 1/0 to save some space" is a ridiculous statement

Answer (score 1):

If you like to put everything inline, you can do this:

```
renderLikeButton(like, likeCount){
    return (<div className={like==1 ? "likeButConAct" : "likeButCon" }>
                <div className="likeB">&nbsp;</div>
                { likeCount > 0 ? <div className="likeCount">{likeCount}</div>: null }
            </div>);
}
```

That way you wont be rendering `.likeCount` div if `likeCount` is 0.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/715u9uvb/

Comment: I tried this : content = <div className="likeButCon"><div className="likeB">&nbsp;</div>{ likeCount > 0 ? <div className="likeCount">{tmpLikeCount}</div>:null}</div> but that did not work.

Comment: here is fiddle with my code: http://jsfiddle.net/715u9uvb/. You can play with it by changing the value of likeCount from 2 to 0. Can you share your broken implementation via fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

what about using the `className` to hide the element?

something like :

```
var cssClasses = "likeButConAct ";

if ( likeCount < 1 ) {
   cssClasses += "hidden";
}
...
return <div className=cssClasses><div ...
```

EDIT

```
    var content;
    var tmpLikeCount;
    var likeCounterComponent;

      if(likeCount > 0){
       likeCounterComponent = <div className="likeCount">{likeCount}</div>
    }


    if(like == 1){
       cssClasses = "likeButConAct"
    }
    else{
      cssClasses = "likeButCon";
    }

    return (
       <div className=cssClasses>
         <div className="likeB">&nbsp;</div>
           { likeCounterComponent }
          </div>);
```

You can add the likeCounter only if there are likes. If there are likes the likeCounterComponent contains the JSX code to render the likes counter, otherwise is undefined and therefore nothing will be rendered.

I haven't tried to run the code, but I guess you got the idea to solve this problem. :D

Comment: Yes but this will still be rendering unnecessary markup.

Comment: @Banshee Right! :D I didn't have  fully understood, what you wanted to achieve. I updated my answer. Let me know if that is what you wanted :D

Answer (score 0):

[Colin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28656917/1385821) looks good to me.. if your issue is with having aspects of rendering extracted to a separate function, you don't HAVE to do that. This works too:

`return (
    <div className={classes}>
        <div className="likeB">&nbsp;</div>
        {this.props.likeCount > 0 && (
            <div className="likeCount">{this.props.likeCount}</div>
        )};
    </div>
)`

Answer (score -1):

```
....
if (likeCount < 1) {
    return "";
}
....
```

Comment: This won't work! Because `""`  is not a React valid component!

Comment: you are returning `<div className="likeButCon"><div className="likeB">&nbsp;</div><div className="likeCount">{tmpLikeCount}</div></div>` - that is also not a component, that is plain text.

Comment: that's a valid JSX which will be translated to javascript by the jsx "compiler". Please read this : http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html

Comment: If it wear plain text, then I could just have a string that I stuff with html but this is not how react works. The return to as @GiuseppePes states render real elements.

Comment: well is `<div></div>` a valid component then? My point is that you return a empty string, or an empty component, whatever is suitable.